# How to remove some density drawable from android library

Tags: android, gradle

My app import admob:

com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0

But it make my app very big, I found there are "drawable-xxxhdpi", "drawable-tvdpi" from this library with very large images, I want to delete(exclude) those from this library.

I used "**resConfigs**" in gradle to just include the density folders I needed before,

but not sure since when the "resConfigs" for density is **not supported**,

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179136

The apk split in density seems not fit my requirements.

**what should I do now?**

Comment: Maybe my comment will be a little off-topic, but they didn't updated their service to support vector drawable? http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Answer (score 4):

You can try splitting and  exluding the xxxhdpi and tvdpi from the releases apks.

```
  splits { 
        density { 
                 enable true  
                 exclude "xxxhdpi", "tvdpi",
        }
   }
```

This will generate differents apks in order to submit later to the playstore. For more information about splits [here.](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits)

Comment: I have to say this answer is not what I really needed. it will split into mdpi, hdpi packages separately.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use [Resource Shrinking](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking) which will remove unwanted resources from libraries. From its docs:

> In addition to removing resources in your project that are not actually needed at runtime, this also **removes resources from libraries** you are depending on if they are not actually needed by your application

However, you'll need to configure Proguard as well, which is a different problem on its own. But if you are already have it configured, just add `shrinkResources true` to your gradle script as in the example below.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear if it didn't work for you or if you're stating that resource shrinking doesn't work with resConfigs. If it is the former, it may be the cause to set `strict` mode as described in the link provided.

Comment: shrinkResources removes unused resources. virsir wants to remove a specific density of used resources.